# Error using CSVLoader from piggybank

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to use CSVLoader from Piggybank. Below are the first two lines of my code:

```
  register 'piggybank.jar' ;
  define CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
```

It throws the following error:

```
  2013-10-24 14:26:51,427 [main] INFO         
  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file    
  system at: file:///
  2013-10-24 14:26:52,029 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Can someone tell me what's going on? I am executing this script from the same folder where my piggybank.jar is located.

Comment: What do you get if you do `jar tf piggybank.jar | grep CSVLoader`?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem when I was experimenting with pig, although it was the XMLLoader for me. The solution that worked for me was to register the entire path to the jar, instead of the relative path. so if the jar is located at /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar run the code as follows:

```
register '/usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar' ;
  define CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. I actually checked out the code again and re-built the jar file and it works fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the code from the url 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/' and re-built the jar file. IT works fine now. :)

Answer (score -1):

The same is working fine
register 'piggybank.jar' ;
A = load '/xmlinput/demo.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('property') as (x:chararray);
B = foreach A generate REPLACE(x,'[\n]','') as x;
C = foreach B generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'.*(?:)([^<]*).*(?:)([^<]*).*');
D =FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN (($0));
STORE D INTO 'xmlcsvpig' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage();