# Pig latin programming

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have a table loaded in a variable in pig whose schema looks like this:
[image]

What I want to accomplish through a pig-latin script is to populate the value "JKL", "PQR" and so on.. in col 4 that is blank for the rest of the rows. The blank rows must copy only the values in the previous cell in the col 4. Check the example below.

The target table should like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if your requirement is to update Col4 value to XYZ for all the records which are having values null or empty then you can use the following code snippet to do the same

```
--Load input data
input_data = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (Col1:chararray, Col2:int, Col3:int, Col4:chararray);

--Perform operation on each record
input_data = FOREACH input_data GENERATE Col1, Col2, Col3, ((Col4 is null or TRIM(Col4) == '') ? 'XYZ' : Col4) as Col4;
```

here assuming that you are holding your input_data then for each record check whether the Col4 value is null or empty, if it is then update it with the desired value (XYZ) or else just use the existing value

Comment: Actually that was the sample data and I cannot check the condition for 'XYZ' the value of Col 4 is not constant. Consider this scenario: Column 1 contains different repetitive values like 'ABC', 'DEF' etc. and for each group of values in Col 1 the first row in Col 4 is populated('XYZ' as shown in the example) and the rest of the rows are blanks. Now I want to populate those rows with whatever the value col 4 is containing for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Col1 is same for all the rows. If Yes, then Use two set of Filter else u have to find the uniq value between col1 & Col4 and remove the NULL value thn use below steps

- Filter_One will capture  Col1 & Col4 where Col4 is not NULL
- Filter_Two will capture Col1, Col2, Col3. Use Join Filter_one &
- Filter_Two, where Filter_two will be printed 1st, 2nd , 3rd Column
  and Filter_one 2nd Column will be pronted at 4th Position,

hope the same will help

The Pig script will be like :

```
Filter_one = foreach Load_Data generate $0 as col1, $3 as col4;
Filter_one_temp =  filter Filter_one by ($1 is not null);
Filter_two = foreach Load_Data generate $0 as col1, $1 as col2, $2 as col3;
Join_filter =  JOIN Filter_two by $0 LEFT, Filter_one_temp by $0;
generetate_output = foreach Join_filter generate $0 as col1, $1 as col2 , $2 as col3,$4 as col4;
store generetate_output into 'dfs_path' using PigStorage(',');
```

as am storing the same with , delimeter so the output will be like

```
(ABC,34,23,XYZ)
(ABC,12,78,XYZ)
(ABC,4,21,XYZ)
(ABC,22,54,XYZ)
(DEF,32,455,JKL)
(DEF,21,45,JKL)
(DEF,45,687,JKL)
(DEF,232,565,JKL)
(DEF,23,32,JKL)
```

Comment: That's what I tried doing in the very beginning. But it fails to produce the desired output. Shows this error : " ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.] "

Comment: In these case the error is while importing the data, if so, please follow the below link, which state to avod import exception [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816078/csv-reading-in-pig-csv-file-contains-quoted-comma) or [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573764/error-using-csvloader-from-piggybank)

Comment: Okay the joins are working fine after I registered the piggybank jar file. But I am unable to design a logic to implement the scenario when there are different groups of rows in Col 1 and the Col 4 values need to populated for their corresponding groups in Col 1. (As shown in the edited version of the question). Can you please help in this regard

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now I am facing a different problem. How to deal with the problem if the Col 4 has two records. And the blanks are filled on this logic that the blank row in Col 4 will take up the value of the previous cell of the col 4.  Please check the edited question. Thanks once again for the efforts you're putting in.

Comment: am not sure abut the Edited question you have asked, but i gess it will be required some more filtering feature as , one way I can suggest by just writing a UDF in Java/Phython which will read the previous column if column value is empty, and will replace the blank with the same.  If I get any more info will share, Also you can take help of another was [Link_check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730249/hadoop-pig-ordered-analytical-functions/31781774#31781774) which was kind of feature taking preivous value check was discussed, thses could help

Comment: Actually I am not very comfortable in using UDF's because I don't have any prior experience in Java/Python programming. I am still looking for a solution in Pig or Hive or even a combination of both would work just fine. Please share if you have any sort of a solution to this problem. thanks